# React Native - Invariant Violation

Tags: javascript, react-native, invariants, activity-indicator

So ive built a Spinner component and i keep getting Invariant Violation.

Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';

const Spinner = ({ size }) => {
    return ( 
        <View style={ styles.spinnerStyle }>
            <ActivityIndicator size={ size || 'large' } />
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = {
    spinnerStyle: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    }
};

export { Spinner };
```

And Im using it here:

```
// Import libs
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import Axios from 'axios';
import AlbumDetail from './albumDetail';
import { Spinner } from './common';

// Create component
class AlbumList extends Component {
    state = {
        albums: [],
        loading: true
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        Axios.get('xxxxx.json').then(response =>
            this.setState({
                albums: response.data,
                loading: false
            })
        );
    }

    renderAlbums() {
        if ( this.state.loading ) {
            return <Spinner size='small'></Spinner>
        }

        return this.state.albums.map( album => 
            <AlbumDetail key={album.title} album={album}/>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView>
                {this.renderAlbums()}
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}

// Export the component for the rest to use
export default AlbumList;
```

The full error is: Invariant Violation:Element type is invalid: expected a string.

I tried just adding:

```
if ( this.state.loading ) {
   return (
       <View style={styles.loading}>
          <ActivityIndicator size='large' />
        </View>
    )
 }
```

And that works. But when used as a component it doesn't want to play. Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: In your `spinner` component, have you tried to use `StyleSheet` from `react-native` to create style properties? eg: `const styles = StyleSheet.create({ container: {...} })`

Comment: Im still learning and havent got to that yet, Ive tried removing the entire style block and still get the error.

Comment: It could be `renderAlbums` has no access to `this`, since you didn't bind it.  Considering write it as an arrow function `renderAlbums = () => {...}`. You should also consider to use `FlatList` instead of `ScrollView`. `ScrollView` doesn't do well for large list. And `album.title` doesn't sound good enough as key.

Comment: In the last code block i use the ActivityIndicator within renderAlbums and it works, so im not sure that would be it.

Comment: Can you post the code for the `./common` file or folder?

Comment: Thanks Pritish, It was my own mistake, i forgot to add export * from './spinner'; to the index of the common folder. You pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Index within common folder did not have:

`export * from './spinner';`

Answer (score 0):

you could also change your export declaration to : 
export default Spinner;

and import declaration to :
import Spinner from './common/Spinner';

but personally I use index.js in my common folder to stock all exports, in this case: 
export * from ./Spinner;

and then I have to import it by calling: 
import { Spinner } from './common';